# Context action on List view for multiple colors

Tags: listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, contextmenu, custom-renderer

Previously I needed to modify the context action color on the list view and that is working with the use of a custom renderer,

```
var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
CGRect rect = new CGRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
CGSize size = rect.Size;
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);

CGContext currentNormalContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();               
currentNormalContext.SetFillColor(Styles.SelectionGreen.ToCGColor());
currentNormalContext.FillRect(rect);
var normalBackgroundImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
currentNormalContext.Dispose();

var t = Type.GetType("Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextActionsCell,
        Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");

var normal = t.GetField("NormalBackground", BindingFlags.Public | 
             BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
if (normal != null) normal.SetValue(null, normalBackgroundImage);

return cell;
```

If there is any possible way to use three of more colors for different scenarios in the same context menu, suggest please.

Comment: Not supported if using `Reflection`

Comment: i didn't get you @ColeXia

Comment: i mean no way to set multi colors in this scenario.

Comment: that's sad. thanks for response.